# JSON Parsing error in Ruby on Rails with ActiveSupport::JSON.decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

This works :

```
body = '{"name":"123"}'

json_string = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode body
```

But this fails

```
body = '{"name":"123//"}'

json_string = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode body
```

If i add a space to the end of string then that works too

```
body = '{"name":"123// "}'
```

I have verified all 3 json strings from http://jsonlint.com/

I am using Rails 2.2.2 , Can anyone help me with this.

I also tried using the JSON gem with
JSON.parse , no help but

Comment: sounds like a bug, try: `json_string = JSON.parse(your_string)`

Comment: ah!!! tried that already

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm interesting indeed. It seems as if escaping the / with ascii notation works (at least in my version of rails, which is 3.2.1, so it can well be that it doesn't work with your version). I think as a workaround this should be all right if it works for your version. ActiveSupport::JSON.decode "{\"foo\":\"\57\57\"}"